# Cells reference not working in Excel VBA 2010 Function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am attempting to write a function that takes a range of data and calculates the ratio of two numbers from the columns provided by the user. I want to print this ratio out at the end of the row, but for some reason I am not able to reference the last cell in the row using the cells function. Instead, the Cells function just keeps providing me the value of that cell and not the cell address. I thought that the cells function provides the address as well. Can someone tell me if this wrong or if my code is wrong?

Here is the code

```
Function calculateRatio(table As Range, numerator As Integer, denominator As Integer,       Optional nameOfRatio As String)
On Error GoTo ExpectedError
    Dim num As Double
    Dim denom As Double
    Dim ratio As Double

    If table.Columns.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox ("Not enough data. Requires at least two or more rows.")
        Exit Function
    End If
    If numerator < 1 Or numerator > table.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox ("Not an acceptable Numerator. Must be greater than zero and less than " & table.Columns.Count)
        Exit Function
    End If
    If denominator < 1 Or denominator > table.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox ("Not an acceptable Denominator. Must be greater than zero and less than " & table.Columns.Count)
     Exit Function
     End If
    For Counter = 1 To table.Rows.Count
        num = table.cells(Counter, numerator)
        denom = table.cells(Counter, denominator)
        ratio = num / denom
        temp = table.cells(counter, table.columns.count)
        temp.Offset(0, 1).Value = ratio
     Next Counter

 Exit Function
ExpectedError:
    Call MsgBox("Something went wrong. Make sure you are referencing columns with numbers and not text." & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description)
End
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the updated code:

```
Function calculateRatio(table As Range, numerator As Integer, denominator As Integer, Optional nameOfRatio As String)
    Dim num As Double
   Dim denom As Double
   Dim ratio As Double
   Dim temp As Range
   Dim counter As Integer

    If table.Columns.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox ("Not enough data. Requires at least two or more rows.")
        Exit Function
    End If
    If numerator < 1 Or numerator > table.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox ("Not an acceptable Numerator. Must be greater than zero and less than " & table.Columns.Count)
        Exit Function
    End If
    If denominator < 1 Or denominator > table.Columns.Count Then
         MsgBox ("Not an acceptable Denominator. Must be greater than zero and less than " & table.Columns.Count)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For counter = 1 To table.Rows.Count
        num = table.cells(counter, numerator)
        denom = table.cells(counter, denominator)
        ratio = num / denom
        Set temp = table.cells(counter, table.Columns.Count)
        temp.Offset(0, 1).Value = ratio
    Next counter
End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to call this function as a UDF from within the Worksheet?

Comment: I am trying to call it as a UDF within the worksheet. Will this cause an issue?

Comment: You're not able to manipulate worksheet cells using a UDF.

Comment: Can this only be done using subroutines? I have been able to manipulate worksheet cells using subroutines before.

Comment: Yes, it can be done using subroutines. See my answer below for some links that explain in a bit more detail. But generally, subroutines can manipulate the worksheet, and functions cannot.  (Functions called from within a subroutine *can*, however this is probably a bad habit to use a Function for anything other than returning values to the Subroutine).

Comment: @derigible kindly check this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273703/excel-2010-vba-user-written-function-modification-of-input-parameter/15274082#15274082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to manipulate worksheet cells from a UDF called from the worksheet.

More information here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15647054/1467082

And here:

http://www.excel-it.com/UDF.htm

generally, subroutines can manipulate the worksheet, and functions cannot.

The exception is that functions called from within a subroutine can, however this is probably a bad habit to use a function for anything other than returning values to the Subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Dim temp as Range` and chagne `temp = table.cells(counter, table.columns.count)` to `set temp = table.cells(counter, table.columns.count)`

Really all you need to do is add the `set`, without it the `Variant` temp is becoming a `long`, with it the `Variant` would become a `Range` object.

Comment: That seems to have done it. What is with the Set rule? I couldn't find anything on why this wouldn't work, and the error was so unhelpful that I had no idea I needed one.

Comment: `Range` is an object, objects need to be set.

Comment: In VBA and VB6 you must use `Set` whenever assigning a variable to an object. If you had `Dim temp as Range`, you would have gotten a more dsecriptive error, indicating you needed a `Set`. Without a `Dim` for temp, temp is considered a `Variant` type and VBA decides for you that it was a `long` and stores the cell value in it, because you didn't use a `Set`. If you used a `Set` VBA would have decided temp was object and assigned it the `Range` object returned from cells. The cells method can return a Range object or the value of the cells.

Comment: @derigible, I would appreciate an upvote and acceptance for my answer, since it solved your problem.

Comment: Actually, after testing it, I am still getting the same issue. I have declared `dim temp as Range` at the top and I have 'set temp = table.cells(counter, table.columns.count)` but it is still not giving me the range object. Instead it is still setting my cell as the value of the cell and not as the range object.

Comment: If you `Dim temp as Range` does not temp have object members? (auto complete when you press period after temp) Also what error do you recieve?

Comment: It does not. The error I am getting is 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: In VBA, click the 'stop' button, then check temp again. `Dim temp as Range` should be inside the function with your other declares. temp must have object members if you declare it as a `Range`, just like table does.

Comment: Also, remove or comment out your error handler, so VBA will break on the line generating the error, what line is that?

Comment: Sorry, temp does have object members. I thought you were referencing table.cells() But for some odd reason temp is being set to 14 and that is not throwing an error. I am debugging it and that is the value the VBA compiler says it has. Perhaps I have some weird problem with my VBA compiler? It breaks in the setting of temp to the ratio value.

Comment: And, I close all instance of excel and restart 1004 is the vaguest error there is and usually means that the automation server for Excel has disconnected somehow and a restart of Excel is required.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27049/discussion-between-motes-and-derigible)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using `Option Explicit` in your code.

You need to declare "temp" as a range.

```
Dim temp As Range ' somewhere at the top of your function

For Counter = 1 To table.Rows.Count
......
Set temp = table.cells(Counter, table.columns.count)
...
Next
```

If you've got the cell coordinates why not offset it manually?

```
table.cells(counter, table.Columns.Count+1).Value = ratio
```

Try this:

```
Function calculateRatio(table As Range, numerator As Integer, denominator As Integer, Optional nameOfRatio As String)
    Dim num As Double
   Dim denom As Double
   Dim ratio As Double
   Dim temp As Range
   Dim counter As Integer

    If table.Columns.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox ("Not enough data. Requires at least two or more rows.")
        Exit Function
    End If
    If numerator < 1 Or numerator > table.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox ("Not an acceptable Numerator. Must be greater than zero and less than " & table.Columns.Count)
        Exit Function
    End If
    If denominator < 1 Or denominator > table.Columns.Count Then
         MsgBox ("Not an acceptable Denominator. Must be greater than zero and less than " & table.Columns.Count)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For counter = 1 To table.Rows.Count
        num = table.cells(counter, numerator)
        denom = table.cells(counter, denominator)
        ratio = num / denom
        table.cells(counter, table.Columns(table.Columns.Count).Column + 1).Value = ratio
        'Set temp = table.cells(counter, table.Columns.Count)
        'temp.Offset(0, 1).Value = ratio
    Next counter
End Function
```

Using `table.columns(table.columns.count).column will make sure that your referencing the correct column, cant think of an example that would cause problems at the moment but better to be safe.

Comment: I am not sure what `Option Explicit` is. Maybe?

Comment: And I would try to do your second option, but for some reason VBA is not recognizing cells as being able to return a range for me. I have no idea what is going on with it.

Comment: `Option Explicit` will prevent you from using undeclared variables. Place it at the beginning of your code, before the `Function`. It is considered good practice.

Comment: Option Explicit means you _must_ declare all your variables in advance. It helps to prevent typing issues. eg: `temp = 1`, VBA might interpret this as an integer when you actually ment a double.

Comment: It still isn't working. It would appear that my Cells function is not returning anything but numbers and not range objects.

Comment: This is not going to work because UDFs called from the worksheet cannot manipulate the worksheet objects.