# Excel VBA Array - Getting #Value! error when trying to dump array into spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this code.
- Objective: I am trying to populate an array with only the match between the two arrays (one array is the reference data I am looking for in the second array).

The code and arrays looks good in the Watches and Locals screens in the developement screen, but when I check the function in the excel spreadsheet it returns a #value! error.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards
rodnei

```
Function FTE_Detail(sref As Range, eref As Range, esource As Range, bplan As Range, eplan As Range) As Variant

    'Application.Volatile

    Dim rreference(34, 0) As String, dumper(150, 6) As String, vsource(17424, 11) As String, k As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim b As Integer, c As Integer, month As Integer, a As Integer
    Dim IDNUMBER As Integer, name As String, empID As String, fromCC As String, tocc As String

    month = Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(7, 6).Value


    For k = 0 To (eref.Row - sref.Row)
        rreference(k, 0) = Worksheets("data").Cells(sref.Row + k, sref.Column).Value
    Next k
    k = 0
    j = 0

    For k = 0 To 11
        For j = 0 To esource.Row
        If Len(Worksheets("data").Cells(70 + j, esource.Column + k).Value) > 250 Then
            vsource(j, k) = Left(Worksheets("data").Cells(70 + j, esource.Column + k).Value, 250)
        Else
            vsource(j, k) = Worksheets("data").Cells(70 + j, esource.Column + k).Value
        End If
        Next j
    Next k

    i = 0
    k = 0
    j = 0
    c = 0
    IDNUMBER = 0

    'hire array
        Do While i <= (eref.Row - sref.Row + 1)
                Do While k <= esource.Row

                    If InStr(vsource(k, month - 2), rreference(i, 0)) Then
                        If vsource(k, month - 3) = "" Then

                            IDNUMBER = IDNUMBER + 1
                            name = Worksheets("data").Cells(70 + k, 1).Value 'Employee name
                            empID = Worksheets("data").Cells(70 + k, 2).Value 'Employee ID

                            dumper(j, 0) = "hire"
                            dumper(j, 1) = Str(IDNUMBER)
                            dumper(j, 2) = name
                            dumper(j, 3) = Str(empID)
                            dumper(j, 4) = "-"
                            dumper(j, 5) = vsource(k, month - 2)
                            dumper(j, 6) = Worksheets("data").Cells(70 + k, 133).Value 'Employee Country

                            j = j + 1

                        Else
                        End If
                    Else
                    End If
                    k = k + 1

                Loop
                k = 0
                i = i + 1
        Loop
    FTE_Detail = dumper()
End Function
```

1. First, I select the range `GH183:GH215`
2. Then press <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste the formula `=FTE_detail(GG183,GG215,DP17424,'2013PlanfromBex'!P3,'2013PlanfromBex'!P2369)`
3. Returns `#value!` in all the cells I selected before.
4. I have done this procedure with other data before and worked. Not sure why is not working in this case.

p.s.: It seems that it builds all the arrays fine in the debug/watches window, only when the functions ends it fails pasting the data from "dumper" to the spreadsheet.

Comment: How are you using/calling this function to assign the data it returns to a range?

Comment: I am selecting a range and writing the function and pressing crtl+shift+enter. tkns :)

Comment: @enderland No, I am trying to return into a range of cells. tkns :)

Comment: It is not possible to use a function to return a value to a range of cells, see [here for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15671691/1467082). You will have to use a subroutine to manipulate a range of cells.

Comment: @DavidZemens: It is possible to return an array from a function, which can be written to the range. Look for array formulas.

Comment: Can you print the content of dumper to the debug window and see if there is any discrepancy?

Comment: @shahkalpesh it is *not* possible to write an array of values to a multi-cell range, using a UDF. This appears to be what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Here is how I tried it. Paste the following function in a bas module. `Function FakeData() As Variant
Dim data(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
data(1, 1) = "a"
data(1, 2) = "aa"
data(2, 1) = "b"
data(2, 2) = "bb"

FakeData = data

End Function`. This returns a 2x2 array. Goto a sheet. Put the cursor on cell A1, select the range A1:B2, press F2, type in `=FakeData()`, press Ctrl + Shift + Enter. Can you see the data as it is returned by the function?

Comment: Apologies for my lack of knowledge, but it works perfectly on the debug window (Watches). Only when it tries to write back to the spreadshet it gives me #value! error. I update my posting with some more details.

Comment: @DavidZemens: Where in the code is OP trying to write directly to cells?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I understood from the OP question that he is calling this function from a worksheet cell. Perhaps I misunderstand, that he says things like, "I am selecting a range of cells..." etc.

Comment: @rodneijr: Can you reduce the data range and see if this fails? You will have to do a divide and conquer on this. See if 10 rows are pasted, go ahead if that works, do it with 20 rows and so on... to nail the data that could be causing this.

Comment: @shahkalpesh great advice. I will try that now.

Comment: @rodneijr: You can put breakpoint in the function as well to step through the code (which will be hit when you press ctrl+shift+enter) and see if the function is throwing any error. OK, I added a `Err.Raise 13` to force throw an error and it returns `#VALUE` :). In summary, your function is raising an error at some point, as a result - it cant return anything, hence `#VALUE`

Comment: @shahkalpesh I used the breakpoints but the function seems to work fine until the end (no errors at all), only when the function steps into FTE_Detail=dumper() and exits I look at the result in the spreadsheet and see that #value! is filled. I will try your "divide to conquer" strategy. Tkns

Comment: @rodneijr: If the function doesn't have any error, it should hit `End Function`. There could be something wrong with your last line. Please check. BTW, do you have a function named `dumper`? Also, make sure the last line is `FTE_Detail = dumper` (without brackets).

Comment: @shahkalpesh `Dumper` is a 160, 5 string array it looks like.

Comment: @rodneijr When the function returns the `#VALUE` have you then tried clicking in the formula bar and pressing `F9` to see what data is in the array? You'll get a #VALUE result if your function attempts to change any part of the Excel environment, including the values of other cells. A function can only return a value or an array of values to the cells from which it was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.
The array content, and function result of 175 lines, surpassed the size of the dumper array, which is 150 lines. If that happens, the result in the excel spreadsheet returns #value!.
I've increased the size of the dumper array and the code worked beautifully.
Thanks for all your help !
Looking forward to contribute more in the future.
Regards
Rodnei

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I see @shahkalpesh beat me to it...

Not really an answer, but to address some of the comments. There's no doubt you *can* use a UDF to return an array of values.  See the example below: select a 2x2 range and enter

`=GetData()`

and use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter it as an array formula.

```
Function GetData()
Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 2)

    arr(1, 1) = "1,1"
    arr(1, 2) = "1,2"
    arr(2, 1) = "2,1"
    arr(2, 2) = "2,2"

    'Err.Raise 13      'uncomment to demonstrate #VALUE in all cells    
    GetData = arr

End Function
```

Comment: After I realized what the OP was asking (assuming this is it), this made me stay late at work to experiment with...

Comment: @tim willians Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do (and done in the past with other data and function). Although, not sure what I am missing now...:(

Comment: @Tim: I have modified the answer to demonstrate the returning of #VALUE (with the help of `Err.Raise`)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a UDF, called from the Worksheet object, to manipulate a range of cells on the worksheet.

[Reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15671691/1467082):

> More information here:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15647054/1467082
>
> And here:
>
> http://www.excel-it.com/UDF.htm
>
> generally, subroutines can manipulate the worksheet, and functions
>   cannot.
>
> The exception is that functions called from within a subroutine can,
>   however this is probably a bad habit to use a function for anything
>   other than returning values to the Subroutine.

Comment: What you're referring to is different from what the OP is doing. You are correct that a UDF cannot directly place information onto the sheet it's called from (or any other sheet). It can however **return** an array, and if the formula was entered as an array fromula then the returned array will populate the selected range.

Comment: Thanks both, it seems I misunderstood the original question.