# Why do I get a 1004 Error when I try to write into a range passed as parameter in a function?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an Excel function and I want that it optionally can write a second result into a

```
Public Function foo(A As String, B As String, C As String, Optional optionalRes As Range = Nothing)

...
If not optionalRes is Nothing then
     optionalRes.Value="Result!"
End If

End Function
```

Unfortunately, this does not work I get this error: Error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error) in procedure foo of Module fooBar.

Is what I am trying to do at least possible?

Thanks in advance for looking at this issue with me!

Comment: It's generally not possible to use a UDF called from the worksheet to manipulate the worksheet objects in any manner whatsoever.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15671691/1467082

Comment: Re: above, there are some hacks to work around this limitation, but I would not advise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **Sub** rather than a **UDF.**

**UDFs** are used to return values rather than change cells via a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple points to consider here...

Note typo in your function definition, which could be avoided by using Option Explicit.  `optionaRes` != `optionalRes`.  But I think that should raise a 424, not a 1004.

Also, worth noting: [It's generally not possible to use a UDF called from the worksheet to manipulate the worksheet objects in any manner whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15671691/1467082).

This may not apply to you, if you are calling this function from elsewhere in VBA code (and *not* from a user-defined worksheet function), but I would still recommend against using functions to manipulate objects.  That should be done by subroutines, and use functions to return values or evaluate expressions, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo to make things clearer.  But actually, I thought it could be convenient to have target where I can return another result from the function. Maybe a better solution would be an array formula, but I have never created such a function... any idea?